# Error while building dll for resource file --error CVT1100: duplicate resource. type:DIALOG, name:4159, language:0x0409

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, resource-files

I trying to create dll from resource files.
I have more than 1 .rc file and want to include in dll.
but i am getting following error

error CVT1100: duplicate resource.  type:DIALOG, name:4159, language:0x0409
error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt.

I searched a lot but couldn't solved yet.

Comment: Well, when you use more than one .rc file then the odds certainly increase to have two dialogs with the same resource id.  Look at the identifier values and pay attention to number 4159.

Comment: @Hans : yes i have checked the 4159 id but its unique through out the project.

Answer (score 0):

I may have had the same problem in my project (but I used Visual Studio 2008).
In my case the problem was that in "Project Properties/Linker/Manifest File/Generate Manifest" when in 
- "Debug" mode the setting should be "No" (setting to "Yes" generates exactly the same error)
- but when in "Release" mode the setting should be "Yes".